# Why does my element move around when the page loads and when javascript executes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider this page: http://www.collegeanswerz.com/adelphi-university/academics/professors/do-professors-explain-things-clearly-are-professors-interesting.

The element in question is "Do they make things easy to understand? Are they interesting?" in the light gray box on the top right.  When the page loads, it starts off high up, and then it moves 30px down.  The same thing happens when you click "Information" in the navbar.

This is the element: `<div id="question_sub" class="well"></div>`.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: 225 Warnings about invalid CSS property, maybe you should fix this at first.

Comment: add your code here to post!!!

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed There isn't anything else that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the 50px margin between the elements then change the `navbar` class to also be 50px

```
.navbar {
     margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Currently it is set at 20px;

Comment: 1) I have a 50px margin-top there.  2) Adding the !important didn't do anything.

Comment: so you want the 50px margin there?

Comment: @Chasser yes, I want the 50px margin there.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to Why does it Happen**

If you try loading your page without javascript the page looks like

[image: page without js]

**Problem**
Your page is very heavily dependent on js for dom elements modification and for styling also. 
**Solution** To avoid this style your page in css as maximum as possible, JS should be used for interaction or making web page attractive.

**Probable Problem**
If you are loading lots of external script which are not related to page content like discus inside head element
**Solution**
Move all the external js from head to end of body if you are not doing it, or you can load them asynchronously. Refer [Mozilla Synch and Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

**Another Way**
If you want content to be loaded from server only when some portion of it has changed then use application cache technique with this the pages will be loaded from client machine so only initial page load will take time for the first load and then it will be quite fast
Check [Using Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)

**Other Ways**

- Compress Javascript and CSS
- Use gzip compression

there are lot of more stuff, search it you will find ocean of knowledge, [reference](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/02/how-to-speed-up-your-website-load-times/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code :-

```
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: You can add `<noscript>` tag again.

Comment: That seemed to improve the page load problem, but not the problem with when I click "Information".  Is it ok to be messing with the Disqus code?

Comment: The above tag is misplaced in your CSS. Check the license, if the link is not neccessary then you can remove it. Its just an hyperlink.

Comment: If link is needed then simply you can place it at right bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem about fusion-margin

Remove this:

```
#college_pages_css .questions {
margin-top: 30px;
```

And try this, it will work fine:

```
#college_pages_css .questions {
margin-top: 0;
```

If you want a margin, put the margin on div#normal ;)

Comment: More infos of this problem: http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/629-fusion-des-marges.html

Sorry, doesn't have the equivalent in english

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having a CSS issue due to the floating elements.

try floating the nav on the left:

```
    #normal > nav {
        float: left;
    }

    .disqus { float: right }
```

and wrap the following elements in a div that is floated to the right, for exemple:

```
    <div class="disqus">
        <div id="question_sub" class="well">Do they make things easy to understand? Are they interesting?</div>
        <p class="stratify" style="display: block;">tip: talk about the best/worst/average cases</p>
        <div id="disqus_thread">
    </div>
```